# View Controller is all white as soon as multiple UITexfields or constraints are added and app is run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I know this question has been asked a ton of times and there are multiple answers.  I have searched the internet for days, and read through hundreds of StackOverflow and other articles regarding this problem.

When I design my view programmatically, everything works until I add multiple UI textfields, the screen turns all white when you run the app.  When I have just 1 textfield and a button, in a UIView or UIStackView, it works and loads.

I have followed the Apple recommended way of setting up the View Controllers, and even pushed this file directly from AppDelegate and it still turns white.

After about 2-3 mints, the app finally does crash with the following code: **Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0)**

When you watch the memory it goes up and up and then crashes every time the this happens.  If i remove all my code and build a basic UI, it worked fine.

I have checked my breakpoints, there are none.  I have cleared my derived data still happens.  I have tried on the iPhone 7, 8 and XR similar as well as a physical iPhone XR and iPhone 6, all the same thing, the entire device is white.

I am looking for some guidance as to where I made a mistake in my code that would be causing this.

Code below, of the LoginView Controller and Login View that is causing the whiteness.

**LoginView.swift**

```
class LoginView: UIView {

    fileprivate enum Text: String {
        case email, password
        case login = "Log In"
    }

    fileprivate enum Font: String {
        case regular = "AvenirNext-Regular"
    }

    let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = Text.email.rawValue.capitalized
        textField.font = UIFont(name: Font.regular.rawValue, size: 17.0)
        textField.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        textField.minimumFontSize = 17.0
        textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        textField.setUpKeyboard(KeyboardType.email, returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType.next)
        return textField
    }()
    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = Text.password.rawValue.capitalized
        textField.font = UIFont(name: Font.regular.rawValue, size: 17.0)
        textField.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        textField.minimumFontSize = 17.0
        textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        textField.setUpKeyboard(KeyboardType.password, returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType.send)
        return textField
    }()
    let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Font.regular.rawValue, size: 17.0)
        button.setTitle(Text.login.rawValue, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        button.setCorner(radius: 5.0)
        return button
    }()

    fileprivate lazy var stackView: UIStackView = { [unowned self] in
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.emailTextField, self.passwordTextField, self.loginButton])
        stackView.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
        stackView.distribution = UIStackView.Distribution.fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.fill
        stackView.spacing = 10.0
        return stackView
        }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setSubviewForAutoLayout(self.stackView)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        self.stackView.snp.remakeConstraints { [unowned self] (make: ConstraintMaker) in
            make.center.equalTo(self)
            make.leading.equalTo(self).offset(40.0)
            make.trailing.equalTo(self).offset(-40.0)

        }

        self.emailTextField.snp.makeConstraints { [unowned self] (make: ConstraintMaker) in
            make.height.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.075)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = LoginView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginButtonPressed), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    weak var loginView: LoginView! { return self.view as! LoginView }
    weak var emailTextField: UITextField! { return loginView.emailTextField }
    weak var passwordTextField: UITextField! { return loginView.passwordTextField }
    weak var loginButton: UIButton! { return loginView.loginButton }

    // MARK: - IBActions
    @objc func loginButtonPressed() {
        print("Login!")
    }

}
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted looks like it would continuously use memory. You could try using instruments or the memory graph debugger to see what is being created in memory. Or just comment out things until the issue stops to narrow down the cause.

Comment: @CraigSiemens Hi Craig, I did that yesterday and I couldn't identify anything.  As i mentioned in my post below, If i comment out the code for the password UITextField, it works, and memory is good.  Only when I add two UITextfields does it turn white and then crash with the memory issue.  Any other suggestions?  I know the code should be right but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't connect your code correctly. Your email text field, password text field and other variables for example should look like: 
`@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!` in order to have your view controller content connected to your code in your class.

Comment: I thought @IBOutlet was only used with storyboards

Comment: so are you saying in this section, i should use @IBOutlet?
    `weak var loginView: LoginView! { return self.view as! LoginView }
    weak var emailTextField: UITextField! { return loginView.emailTextField }
    weak var passwordTextField: UITextField! { return loginView.passwordTextField }
    weak var loginButton: UIButton! { return loginView.loginButton }`

Comment: that did not work at all, XCode errored out and said they were not mutable.  Which makes sense, since IBOutlet is for storyboards

Answer (score 0):

Check your constraints. Are they all correct? Making your constraints on the storyboard itself might help. Also, could you send screenshots?

Comment: I am doing my entire app programmatically.  I am re-writing it from scratch as it looks so horrible with storyboard.  Trying to figure out auto-layout and constraints is a nightmare and I made the mistake of thinking it may be easier with all code.  Auto-layout to me is that it should do everything automatically.   Anyway, What I did notice was that when I add 2 or more UI textfields to my view controller, it turns white when I run it, even without constraints.  But when I have one it loads.  The strangest thing I every have seen.

Comment: if you look at my code above and I comment out the entire PasswordTextField closure, the app runs with no white screen.  Baffling.